# How does structure array copying work in C?

Tags: c, arrays, structure, strcpy

This is the code that I want to run in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    struct record {
        char name[2];
        char letter;
    };

    struct record student[10];
    strcpy(student[0].name,"t");//copy "t" to first struct's name variable
    strcpy(student[1].name,"ri");//copy "ri" to second struct's name variable
    student[0].letter='a';//copy "a" to first struct's letter variable
    student[1].letter='b';//copy "b" to second struct's letter variable
    printf("%s %s %c %c", student[0].name, student[1].name, student[0].letter, student[1].letter);
}
```

The output that I am expecting is: t ri a b

However I am getting: t rib a b

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> strcpy(student[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).name,"ri");//copy "ri" to second struct's name
>   variable

This is definitely wrong. `"ri"` is actually three characters due to null terminator also. So you are copying three bytes to array which has 2 bytes, thus invoking [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) with this.

Comment: So what can I do? Should I just increase the size of the name variable in my struct from name[2] to name[3] for it to work in this case?

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 Yes it will work in this case if you increase to 3. But maybe you need larger array

Comment: Oh doing so, it worked. Thanks a lot for your prompt help. I knew about null character but forgot about it when I was writing this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `name` is an array having two `char`s. OTOH, the size of `"ri"` is three characters, including the null-terminator.

So, by saying

```
  strcpy(student[1].name,"ri");
```

you're overrunning the memory. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)

> [...] The strings may not overlap, and the destination string `dest` must be large enough to receive the copy. [...] If the destination string of a `strcpy()` is not large enough, then anything might happen.

Once you hit UB, the program behavior cannot be justified.

To be able to hold `"ri"`, you need to change

```
char name[2];
```

to

```
char name[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    struct record {
        char name[3];
        char letter;
    };

    struct record student[10];
    strcpy(student[0].name,"t");//copy "t" to first struct's name variable
    strcpy(student[1].name,"ri");//copy "ri" to second struct's name variable
    student[0].letter='a';//copy "a" to first struct's letter variable
    student[1].letter='b';//copy "b" to second struct's letter variable
    printf("%s %s %c %c",student[0].name,student[1].name,student[0].letter,student[1].letter);
}
```